# Django-paypal doesn't create IPN tables in DB - how to fix?

Tags: django, paypal-ipn, django-south, django-paypal

After installing [django-paypal](https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal), and doing a *syncdb* - when I logged in as admin, I didn't see any Paypal IPN tables in the database. After some searching, I found a post on [Integrating Django and Paypal](http://od-eon.com/blogs/nai/django-paypal-step-step-integration/), which said:

> Just in case anyone is running into DB related problems, django-paypal
>   uses South to handle it's model creation. So running ./manage.py
>   syncdb will *not* create the Paypal related tables.

Wups. So my question is, is there any simple way to create the tables *other than* installing South? Or is that the only real option?

(Yes, I'm sure I should install South at some point - right now, it's just one more package to install/configure, that needs to be learned - and might break things. :)

Comment: @Srinivas, is there a reason for the 'python' tag? Other than Django being *written* in Python, my question has nothing to do with the Python language.

Comment: ,since many users subscribe to python than django,so it can be reached to wider readers.so there is a chance that u will get answer quickly!!! :)

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy, ah, thanks, but not sure that's a good reason to put an unrelated tag. I presume anyone interested in Django already follows that tag. Anyway, removing `python` tag.

Answer (score 2):

If a package is managed by South, the easiest way is to just use South. South doesn't require any configuration - all you have to do is add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` and run syncdb. After you've installed South, you are in no way obligated to manage your own code with it - you can just keep using it for django-paypal. Don't be afraid that it's complicated to get started with it - it really isn't.

As for your question, I believe there may be a work around having to use South. The first thing that comes to mind is going into django-paypal's installation directory and removing the South migrations manually - but I haven't tried it, it's just a thought. However, I think installing South would be way easier in this case.